# StarTeam API Permission

Tags: c#, api, permissions, starteam

I'm developing a client app with C#.NET.
I need to get all the Permissions in the StarTeam which are assignable to a Project, View, or Folder.

StarTeam Cross Platform users know that there is a dialog named "Access Rights".
Categories (Project, View, Folder) are listed at the left side and Permissions are listed at the right side in the dialog.

Permissions are not just listed, but grouped logically. And, some permissions become visible or invisible depending on the selected category on the left side.

This is what I want to have in my app. Listing permissions in a grouped way and making them visible or invisible according to selected category.

Is there anyone who can show me the way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Poor Borland.  Anders works at Microsoft today.  He's pretty sure it has nothing to do with C#.  There are Borland forums, I think, CodeGear, Embarcadero, somthing like that.

Comment: @Closer: Why is this too localized?

Answer (score 1):

Look at AccessRightsManager and the GetEffectiveACL method - doing it by hand is a pain.

The list of possible permissions is inside the Permission type.  I don't believe there is any grouping as is shown in the dialog other than the names of the properties themselves.  (ITEM_SEE_HISTORY vs. VIEW_CREATE_VIEW_LABEL)

Comment: Hello Jeremy, thanks for your reply.
I contacted with MicroFocus and they accept that SDK does not expose this feature. (Grouping Permissions). And, I wrote and grouped them by hand.

But now, I have another problem regarding AccessRightsManager.
When I try to get effective acl of a folder with following code, I get a error of : "Exception of type 'Borland.StarTeam.SDKRuntimeException' was thrown."

Code:

BS.AccessRightsManager arm = new BS.AccessRightsManager(server); BS.EffectiveACL effectiveAcl = arm.GetEffectiveACL(selectedFolder);

What may be the problem?

Comment: Huh, using the latest 2009 .NET SDK, I got the same internal SDK exception.  I confess I haven't tried using ARM in a while.  I'll see if I can figure it out or get it going on 2008R2.